# Can deleted snapchat messages be recovered?

Tags: ios, iphone, data-recovery

If there are chats that have been deleted, is there a way to recover these with any recovery tools, or are they gone forever?

Comment: This is not really a security question.  Your best bet is google or contacting snapchat.  Presumably though the answer is "no".

Comment: Recovered by you? Probably not. Recovered by the company for their own purposes? Probably.

Comment: Was just wondering if there was any recovery tools that could. Like high tech ones? Forensic stuff

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can try data recovery software available to restore Snapchat messages. There are many tools. I can't promise 100% recovery of all deleted messages. Many messages can be recovered depending on overwriting/changes of data.

https://www.drfonelab.com/recover-lost-snapchat-messages.html

https://www.ibeesoft.com/recover-iphone/snapchat-message-recovery-iphone.html